# MSTest results output to be shown in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

i made the following changes to get MSTest results output to be shown in CruiseControl.NET

1) For Dashboard - in dashboard.config added a reference to the Mstest 2008 xsl file under buildReportBuildPlugin

xsl\MsTestReport2008.xsl
2) For email - in ccservice.exe.config added the reference to the same xsl file under xslFiles section

But Point 1 is working fine and i am able to see the mstest result on dasgboard. but in mail it just print build failed.it should also displayed summary of mstest but in mail i am not getting it...?

Also i am using cruisecontrol.net version 1.5.7256.1

So can i get any suggestion on this so that in mail notification it should also display mstest summary/report with build failed message...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting MSTest output to show in CruiseControl.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209972/getting-mstest-output-to-show-in-cruisecontrol-net)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the MsTestReport2008.xsl file in ccnet/server/xsl ? Does restart the IIS service help?